# python-twitter: get_oauth( ) giving unexpected error

Tags: python, oauth, twitter-oauth, python-twitter

I am new to python and I have been making codes to scrap twitter data on python.
Below are my codes:

```
import csv
import json
import twitter_oauth
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/jdschnieder/Documents/Modules")
print sys.path

#gain authorization to twitter
consumer_key = 'xdbX1g21REs0MPxofJPcFw'
consumer_secret = 'c9S9YI6G3GIdjkg67ecBaCXSJDlGw4sybTv1ccnkrA'
get_oauth_obj = twitter_oauth.GetOauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
get_oauth_obj.get_oauth()
```

the error occurs at the line:

```
 get_oauth_obj.get_oauth()
```

the error message is as follows:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-36-5d124f99deb6> in <module>()
  --> 1 get_oauth_obj.get_oauth()

 /Users/jdschnieder/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
 twitter_oauth-0.2.0-py2.7.egg/twitter_oauth.pyc in get_oauth(self)
    95         resp, content = client.request(_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, "GET")
    96         if resp['status'] != '200':
 -> 97             raise Exception('Invalid response %s' % resp['status'])
    98 
    99         request_token = dict(self._parse_qsl(content))

 Exception: Invalid response 401
```

why is this error occurring, and what are possible solutions to the error?

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Twitter library you're using does not support Twitter API v1.1. Instead of twitter_oauth, use one of the Python libraries listed [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries). For example, you can use Tweepy, following the [documentation for OAuth Authentication](http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/auth_tutorial.html#oauth-authentication)